# Is A* or Dijkstra more efficient for a pedestrian navigation system?

Tags: navigation, dijkstra

I want to implement a pedestrian navigation system  and I came across the ***A*-*** and ***Dijkstra*** algorithm.
As far as I understand correctly the A * is fundamentally more efficient than Dijkstra's search algorithm, because A * is specifically designed to find the shortest path between two points.

Each node has its position on the respective card. This position has no global reference to the entire field, but only a local on the corresponding map.
With existing global references of the individual positions, the horizontal distance of a node will be easily calculated and the advantages of A * full will be exhausted. Without the global references, it is very difficult to calculate meaningful values ​​for the heuristic.

So if that's the case that I have many different layers and multiple cards which algorithm is better?

Comment: A* needs a heuristic function h with the cost function. If there is a good one, A* can be much faster than pure Dijkstra. If there is none, A* is the same than Dijkstra. If you get h wrong, A* can be much slower than Dijkstra.

Comment: Yeah but does it also depend if the nodes are globally available for A* (e.g. you need a heuristic based on each known node and if some nodes are not known you can't use the heuristic anymore)

Comment: I’m not sure if i get you ... in A*, a heuristic has as parameter only the node you just work on (and perhaps some constants), but no ather node. And of an unknown node, you cannot calculate anything.

Comment: Suppose you have a playing field with several cards. The nodes have no global relationships to each other, but only on their respective map. Can you find a suitable heuristic at all in this scenario?

Comment: I can’t see a heuristic that would accelerate A* compared to Dijkstra with unmodified distance.